# Guideline for users to view

Tags: users

I have a website coming up soon and the editors for this website dosen't know how to use Drupal. I have made a content guideline for users to follow(guideline for like uploading content and such), now I want this guideline to appear on the website for only certain roles to view. In my example the role editor has the only permission to view this content and no one else.

Do you guys got any clue of how to fix this and also where I should place it? On their account page or just in the navbar?

Thanks for any tips and advice

Comment: It's not clear what is the issue exactly. Also second question (where to place it) is something that is really based on preferences, not something that has a universal answer, so I suggest either paraphrasing it or taking it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach can be using content access module.So basically while creating content type you will get option to share content type with user role you want to.

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per
>   content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.

Other approach does not require any module, and will be simple and out of the box.

1. Create a content type, lets say editor_guide.
2. While creating the content type opt to keep the nodes unpublished.
3. Now create nodes,which can be single node(copying the complete guide to one node),multiple node(dividing the guide content into chunks as separate nodes),you can also keep the guide as file field on node.
4. Create a view of display type page with path say editor-guide.
5. In views you will get option to set permission for the page, set the permission for editor, in the views filter remember to change status for content for unpublished.
6. Now in you nav-bar menu block add a menu item, link it to editor-guide(or whatever).

This link will be automatically visible to editor role only.